# Usage of “bunt”

Tags: usage

I thought *bunt* was a neutral term that simply means *colorful* or *multicolored.*  One German-speaking friend recently told me that *bunt* was not neutral at all and often carried a judgement.  For example, *ein buntes Kleid* can be positive and complimentary, whereas *ein buntes Bild* is mildly pejorative and describes a riot of colors out of harmony with each other.

My dictionary translates *bunt* as *gaudy, motley, ragtag* which would be highly insulting in English when applied to someone's clothing.

What are the precise rules for using *bunt?*

Comment: uniformity huh that is a rather large generalizaton

Comment: I don't think it is the *word* bunt that carries that judgement, but rather that in certain contexts the fact of being colourful as such is seen as positive or negative.

Comment: Yet, all the etymologies I have seen do not link the English 'bunting' [strings of pendant flags, generally quite colourful] to the German word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, *bunt* basically has three definitions:

1. colorful
2. varied, diverse
3. disordered

The English words I've provided as definitions are very spot-on; and though, they are quite general. Depending on context, you can find a better translation; however, you would certainly use a different word in German then, too.
That is, the words you've mentioned are possible translations, but do not reflect the pure meaning. All these words already add some connotation that the context may provide.

*Bunt*, in general, is neutral. It means colorful.
Using *bunt* in "a colorful picture" may or may not be pejorative. An example where I consider it (most times) approving is when a child draws a picture which is colorful; as long as it's not too colorful, but then you call it "zu bunt". And something being *too much* of something is negative in both languages English and German.

With reference to the other two definitions, *bunt* can also be approving or disapproving. "Ein bunter Nachmittag" (lit. *a colorful afternoon*) can be both good or bad. Context will clarify.

Comment: The negative connotation related to a picture might also derive from the fact, that, if the only remarkable quality of the picture is that it is colorful, ... well it might not be a good picture after all :)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the concept of a "colorful afternoon."  "Colorful" in English usually means literal colors, although there are some fixed phrases such as a "colorful character."  Would a "colorful afternoon" in German refer literally to colors (e.g., a Mexican fiesta) or to a general adventure that is rich in diverse experiences, as your definition (2) above states?

Comment: @DanLeifker Yes, it belongs to definition 2. That's a good definition you've just given "a adventure that is rich in diverse experiences".

Answer (score 2):

"Bunt" literally means "multi-colored" or "variegated." Whether or not it is "neutral" depends largely on the social context.

The "Anglo-Saxon" preference is for "uniformity." Under this ethos, attributes like "motley" or "variegated" aren't exactly virtues. That holds true for American English, British English, and German. In this regard, the English and German connotations are similar (and negative).

Such a word might have a more positive connotation in "Latin" or Mediterranean" languages and cultures.

Even so, "bunt" might be considered complimentary in regards to clothing (depending on the wearer), but probably not in art (except "modern" art).